# create dialog from listener

Tags: java, swing, dialog, focus, event-listener

Faced the following situation. I have a list of projects in JCombobox. Changing the line in the combo box causes my itemStateChanged method to be called from the ItemListener interface. And it is right. But here I need to ask the user if he/she is sure of this, because he/she changed something in the old project, and it would be nice to save these changes (or not, since this is an accidental error, or not leave the old project at all). I went beyond a simple JOptionPane.showQuestionMessage and built my own complex dialog. With different fields, trees, tables and others, allowing the user to make an informed choice between "Yes", "No" and "Cancel". And here is an ambush!

The dialog after pack() and setVisible(true) opens but doesn't get focus! The focus is still on the combo box, in which the current line was changed. Probably, this is also correct, since after confirming and possibly saving the changes, the user should be given the opportunity to continue clicking projects.

Is it possible to call modal dialog window without affecting the drop-down list?

Even if we accept the loss of focus in the combo box and the closing of the drop-down list in it, then how  transfer focus to the dialog after setVisible(true)? Using dialog.requestFocus before dialog.setVisible (true) doesn't help. Now the "Yes" button must be clicked twice. The first click is to transfer focus, the second is to press the button itself.

Or am I missing something simple? I would be grateful for any suggestions!

Comment: 1) make sure you are using a "modal" dialog. 2) If that doesn't work then wrap the code that creates the dialog in a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`. This will allow the  drop down to close before the dialog is displayed so the dialog will keep focus.

Comment: @camickr Seems I have not enough reputation to mark solution. Indeed, inserting creating modal dialog in SwingUtilities.invokeLater() solved the problem with focus.

Answer (score 1):

Following the @camickr 's advice the solution is:

```
  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      appData.askAndSaveCurProject(project);                           
    }
  });
```